# How to list names and descriptions of all loaded kernel modules

Tags: bash

**How to list module names and descriptions in the following format?**

```
...
ext4 Fourth Extended Filesystem
video ACPI Video Driver
...
```

To list all loaded kernel modules (with some usage info for each one)

```
$ lsmod
```

To list only the module names (first column of lsmod, remove title)

```
$ lsmod | cut -d " " -f 1 | tail -n +2
...
ext4
video
...
```

To list all the descriptions of loaded kernel modules

```
$ sudo modinfo $(lsmod | cut -d " " -f 1 | tail -n +2) |grep "description" | cut -c17-
...
Fourth Extended Filesystem
ACPI Video Driver
...
```

**How to combine both names and descriptions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this with a standard shell:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

lsmod | {
  read -r _ || exit 1 # Ignore header line
  while read -r name _; do
    modinfo -F description "$name" | {
      read -r desc || true # Ignore read failure if no description
      # Print at least a line per module
      printf '%-24s %s\n' "$name" "$desc"
      # Iterate remaining description lines if any
      while read -r desc; do
        # Print description line without repeating module name
        printf '%-24s %s\n' '' "$desc"
      done
    }
  done
}
```

- `lsmod | while`: Pipe the `lsmod`'s output to a `while` loop
- `while read -r name _; do`: Iterate reading the module name, and ignore “size” and “used by” into `_` place-holder variables.
- `modinfo -F description "$name" | while`: Query `modinfo`'s description, and pipe the output to a `while` loop as it can be multiple lines.
- `while read -r desc; do`: Iterate reading each description line.
- `printf '%-24s %s\n' "$name" "$desc"`: Print formatted module name and description line.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r name; do
    printf "%s\t\t%s\n" "${name}" "$(sudo modinfo "$name" | grep "description" | cut -c17-)"
done <<< "$(lsmod | cut -d " " -f 1 | tail -n +2)"
```

1. Read all the names `"$(lsmod | cut -d " " -f 1 | tail -n +2)"`
2. [Loop through each line](https://superuser.com/questions/284187/bash-iterating-over-lines-in-a-variable)
3. `printf` the name, and add the result of `sudo modinfo ...` behind it

Small section of example output:

```
...
psmouse              PS/2 mouse driver
virtio_blk           Virtio block driver
virtio_net           Virtio network driver
...
```

Copy-Paste one-liner;

```sh
while IFS= read -r name; do printf "%s\t\t%s\n" "${name}" "$(sudo modinfo "$name" | grep "description" | cut -c17-)"; done <<< "$(lsmod | cut -d " " -f 1 | tail -n +2)"
```

Comment: Using %-24s %s\n instead of %s\t\t%s\n reveals that it doesn't handle multiple descriptions lines if any.